# Trouble while running python program

Tags: module, python-3.5, pyperclip, pythoninterpreter

I have made a program `asp.py` and imported `pyperclip` module :

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('hrllo world')
pyperclip.paste()
```

and when I run this from terminal, with

```
python3 asps.py
```

it does not display any result 
what could be the reason that `'hrllo world'` does not display?

[image: result of above command]

and moreover, if I run the same commands individually form python shell, it goes well. Have a look at it:

[image: Result of individual code]

Comment: I was expecting that it would display output as "hrllo world", but now i get it what was the error.Thanks anyway:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it does not display

of course it does not, because there's no portion of your code that outputs  anything like `print`.

Also, running commands in python shell is not directly equivalent to running in "normal" way, due to the subtle differences (i.e. if you just set variable like `a=15` and then do just `a` you will see 15 in shell. In normally executed program you won't as you need to explicitly output the data using said `print` or others.

Comment: Thanks ! That helped , such a rookie mistake  I made